# specifying and executing another pom.xml using a current pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am wondering if it is possible to execute a POM from current POM?

I have a POM which generate a target/generated-code/POM.xml (I need a way to access the generated POM and execute it)

Please suggest, can it be done using goals?

Comment: Can you explain why your are creating a pom file within a Maven project? What kind of problem are you trying to solve? Please add much more details what exactly you are doing etc.

Comment: Please add the problem you want to solve with this approach. It is likely that there is better and more direct solution to your original problem.

Comment: @khmarbaise I am not creating a POM inside a maven project (lets say I have a project testJavaOpenApi --> I have a POM, inside the POM I am adding a plugin (of OpenApi codegen maven plugin, and inside the plugin, i need to specify <inputSec> which will have my spec file which is a YAML file.) So, when I am doing mvn clean compile --> OpenApi codegen plugin will generate a project inside TARGET folder, and that project will have its own POM.xml. BUT, doing that the compile process is failing because I have no dependencie in POM.xml for which I ran.

Comment: @khmarbaise ....but if I am going inside the target folder, and doing mvn compile for the POM that got generated using OpenApi code gen maven plugin, TARGET is being generated for it.